# How do I generate a UUID in Crystal?

Tags: uuid, crystal-lang

I'm experimenting with the Crystal standard library and was wondering how to generate a UUID? The `UUID.new(..)` constructors all seem to expect arguments, but how do I just generate a random one?

Answer (score 2):

I was looking at the wrong part of the standard library documentation -- just a bit below the constructors is the [`.random` class method](https://crystal-lang.org/api/1.0.0/UUID.html#random(random=Random::Secure,variant=Variant::RFC4122,version=Version::V4)-class-method), which requires no arguments and generates a new UUID.

Usage example:

```
require "uuid"
puts "New UUID: #{UUID.random}" 

# Output:
# New UUID: bfc5a3cf-a138-4323-881b-764e1e798ce4
```

Comment: I created a PR to fix this in the API docs. The `.random` and `.empty` methods should show up in the *Constructors* section.
https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal/pull/10539